# Efficient way of processing byte array which contains a mixture of encodings

Tags: java

I have some data in a byte array, retrieved earlier from a network session using non-blocking IO (to facilitate multiple channels).

The format of the data is essentially

```
varint: length of text
UTF-8: the text
```

I am trying to figure out a way of efficiently extracting the text, given that its starting position is undetermined (as a varint is variable in length). I have something that's really close but for one small niggle, here goes:

```
import com.clearspring.analytics.util.Varint;
// Some fields for your info
private final byte replyBuffer[] = new byte[32768];
private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName ("UTF-8");

// ...
  // Code which extracts the text
    ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(replyBuffer);
    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(byteInputStream);
    int textLengthBytes;

    try {
      textLengthBytes = Varint.readSignedVarInt (inputStream);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
     // I don't think we should ever get an IOException when using the
     // ByteArrayInputStream class
       throw new RuntimeException ("Unexpected IOException", e);
    }
    int offset = byteInputStream.pos(); // ** Here lies the problem **
    String textReceived = new String (replyBuffer, offset, textLengthBytes, UTF8);
```

The idea being that the text offset in the buffer is indicated by byteInputStream.pos(). However that method is protected.

It seems to me that the only way to get the "rest" of the text after decoding the varint is to use something that copies it all into another buffer but that seems rather wasteful for me.

Constructing the string directly from the underlying buffer should be fine, because after this I don't care anymore for the state of byteInputStream or inputStream. So I am trying to figure out a way to calculate offset, or, put another way, how many bytes Varint.readSignedVarInt consumed. Perhaps there is an efficient method of converting from the integer value returned by Varint.readSignedVarInt to the number of bytes that would have taken up in the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can find the offset of the string in the byte array:

- You can create a subclass of `ByteArrayInputStream` that gives you access to the `pos` field. It has protected access so that subclasses can use it.
- If you want something more generally applicable, create a subclass of `FilterInputStream` that counts the number of bytes that have been read. This is more work and probably not worth the effort though.
- Count the number of bytes that encode the `varint`. There are at most 5.

  ```
  int offset = 0; while (replyBuffer[offset++] < 0);
  ```
- Calculate the number of bytes needed to encode a `varint`. Each byte encodes 7 bits so you can take the position of the highest 1 bit and divide by 7.

  ```
  // "zigzag" encoding required since you store the length as signed
  int textLengthUnsigned = (textLengthBytes<<2) ^ (textLengthBytes >> 31);
  int offset = (31 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(textLengthUnsigned))/7 + 1
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the broad range of options. 2nd option might actually be worth the effort when it comes to implementing other parts of this particular protocol. Probably going to accept this answer, I just need to improve my knowledge of varint so I can verify options 3&4 are indeed correct.

Comment: Could you clarify your comment "// "zigzag" encoding required since you store the length as signed"? This number is always going to be less than 2**31 (ie less than 2GB of text!) so whether it is signed/unsigned does not matter?

Comment: The varint encoding for "signed integers" (as used by  `readSignedVarInt` and `writeSignedVarInt`) uses a mapping where positive ints map to even positive ints and negative ints map to odd positive ints, see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#types

Comment: int offset = 0; while (replyBuffer[offset++] < 0); is the easiest way to go. Works by way of the fact that "each byte in a varint, except the last byte, has the most significant bit (msb) set" (and is therefore negative)